# Re-write an equation in another form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation:
$$
\tan\big(\theta\big) =  \dfrac{V^2}{R*g}
$$
where :

($\theta$) is (**variable**).

(V)  is  (**variable**).

(R)  is  (**variable**).

(g)  is  (**constant**).

can we do the following rearrangements to the equation :

we know that:$$w = \dfrac{V}{R}$$
1. Substitute in the first equation:

$$w = \dfrac{g * tan(\theta)}{V}$$
2.  From the first equation we can say that:
$$
V = \sqrt{R*g*tan(\theta)}
$$
3. Substitute with **V** in **w** equation, we get:
$$
w = \dfrac {g *\tan(\theta)}{\sqrt{R*g*tan(\theta)}}
$$
4. At the end **w** can be written as:
$$
w = \sqrt{\dfrac {g *\tan(\theta)}{R}}
$$
I am asking this question because i am confused with the step number (2) i do not know is this  right or wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the question now?

Comment: V= +/- sqrt...  You might find things don't quite work out...

Comment: i have edited it

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner for a second, i have confused that if i can use v again from the same equation to substitute again in the same equation

Comment: It is fine. You could also start with $$w^2 = \frac{V^2}{R^2}$$ and substitute in your original equation.

Comment: why, to decrease the number of the steps?

Comment: It avoids your double substitution. Is that not what you wanted or were worried about?

Comment: no, but i was asking about the steps taken above are ok or not. but you have approved it so thank you

Comment: It appears that $v$ represents velocity, $\omega$ represents angular velocity, $g$ represents the acceleration due to gravity in the Earth's gravitational field, and $R$ represents a radius.  If so, then $v$ and $\omega$ can assume negative values.

Comment: No, $v$ and $\omega$ are magnitudes of vectors, so they are non-negative.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig yes i wrote them and they are representing what you have stated, but they are not representing vectors

Comment: @N.F.Taussig what if they are representing vectors? what should be changed?

Comment: Vectors have a direction, which is why they could be negative.  Therefore, you would need $\pm$ signs outside the square roots.